# how do they differentiate between internal and external application using Oauth2

Tags: facebook, web-services, rest, oauth-2.0, authorization

Suppose I have a Web Service API defined and would like to implement OAuth Server to provide access to third-party mobile application and my own mobile application.

As these two types of application(internal/external) will try to access my API, what are the possible mechanisms that my authentication server differentiate them?

As an Example, Consider a Facebook app and Lyft (External).While login to facebook through Lyft, fb recognizes it as third-party app and ask for permission level but in Facebook(Internal) app they don't ask permission level. How do they do it?

*Please correct me, if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

OAuth 2.0 differentiates between clients/applications by granting them their own set of client credentials in the form of an identifier and a shared key, respectively named `client_id` and `client_secret`.

Comment: So, does that mean internal applications also have an identifier and shared key but they have would have higher permissons?

Comment: exactly, at runtime the client gets an access token that is associated with certain "scopes" i.e. permissions that are specific to that client; that token is granted based on the client identification

Comment: So even though it is an in-house application, the application still calls the /oauth/token endpoint for example?